# assign custom reduction value to variable

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I calculate the average of specific column with below code:

```
var averageGroup = all.reduce(
            function(p, v) {
                ++p.number;
              p.StockDay += v.StockDay ;
              p.average= p.StockDay/p.number ;    
                return p;
        },
            function(p, v) {
                --p.number;
              p.StockDay -= v.StockDay ;
              p.average= p.StockDay/p.number ;  
                return p;
        },
            function() {
                return {
                number: 0,
                average: 0,
                StockDay : 0,

    };
  }
);
```

Now I want to assign this average value to variable because I will use it within my dc.barChart.
I want to assign different colors to columns where value is more than average.

The problem is when I make filter on charts it redraw the barchart but it doesn't change color according to new average which is calculated in averageGroup above.

```
   var stockChart= dc.barChart('#stock') 
                            .width(2000)
                            .height(600)
                            .margins({top: 10, right: 0, bottom: 130, left: 80})
                            .dimension(areaDim)
                            .group(areaGroup)
                            .valueAccessor(function(p) {                        
                                    return p.value.avg; 
                            })     
                            .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
                            .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
                            .ordering(function(p) {return -p.value.avg})
                            .colors(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["positive", "negative"])
                              .range(["#FF0000", "#00FF00"]))
                              .colorAccessor(function(p) {
                            if (p.value.avg> mean) {
                                return "positive";
                            }
                             return "negative";
                            })                       
                            .elasticX(true)
                                .renderlet(function (chart) {
                                    chart.selectAll("g.x text")
                                    .attr('dx', '-40')
                                    .attr('transform', "rotate(-45)");
                                    })   
                            .elasticY(true)
                            .yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format('.3s'))
```

I calculate the mean variable shown below: But it gives me static value and doesn't change as I filter charts.

```
var selectedData = data.filter(function(d) {
            return d.StockDay;
  })
 mean = d3.mean(selectedData,function(d) { return d.StockDay]})
```

But I want this mean variable come from averageGroup custom reduction function so when I filter charts and average changes my dc.barchart will change color according to the filtered average.

Comment: I don't understand: it looks like you are already using [crossfilter.groupAll()](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#crossfilter_groupAll) to calculate the mean across all values, so why do you also calculate it using `d3.mean`? Seems like you could just use `averageGroup.value().average` instead of `mean` in your color accessors.

Comment: Hello Gordon. I used it on my code and it works. I was not sure how to do that. Thank you .

Comment: Ah, that's great! Wasn't sure if I was looking at the right problem, thanks for following up.